# Pass variables to base layout from extending pug/jade template

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

I would like to set a class on the body tag by declaring a variable in a template that extends a base layout.

When I try, the `body_class` variable is `undefined` in the layout.

It appears the layout is executed before the extending template, or they are executed in different scopes or something.

Is there another way? Would a mixin work here?

**_layout.jade:**

```
doctype html
html(lang="en-au")
    head
        meta(charset="utf-8")
        block css
    body(class=(body_class || "it-did-not-work"))
        block header
        block content
        block footer
```

**home.jade:**

```
var body_class = 'i-am-the-home-page'
extends _layout
block header
    h1 home
```

Comment: Similar to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15035624/jade-templating-variable-scope-in-includes

Answer (score 89, accepted):

Ah ha! Figured it out.

Create a block at the top of the base layout and add your variables in there.

**_layout.jade:**

```
block variables
doctype html
html(lang="en-au")
    head
        meta(charset="utf-8")
        block css
    body(class=(body_class || "it-did-not-work"))
        block header
        block content
        block footer
```

**home.jade:**

```
extends _layout
block variables
    - var body_class = 'i-am-the-home-page'
block header
    h1 home
```

Comment: thank you sir, exactly what I was looking for. So the scope is on the root template being extended?

Comment: This is missing a dash before the var statement.  It should be `- var body_class = 'i-am-the-home-page'`.  Otherwise the code will not be compiled as JavaScript.

Comment: I found this, which has examples of how to actually implement this. I found it helpful - https://gist.github.com/viktorbezdek/9665226

Comment: This should totally be included in the Pug's documentation. There's no way that this is an obvious usage of a block.