# How to add background image to only one page in Jade

Tags: html, css, pug, background-image, template-engine

I know how to do this in regular HTML, I can add a class to the body tag and modify that tag in css, but I am using Jade so I don't have a body tag to play with. My Jade file which looks like this.

index.jade (the only page that I want to have a background image in)

```
extends layout

block main
    .container
        h1 Hello world
```

I tried doing

```
body.index {
    background: url(images/background.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

This does not work. I also tried adding a backgroundimage class to the container class and make its width and height 100% like below but it is not optimal because there is another div that comes before it in layout.jade (the file index extends) which gives an awkward spacing on this page.

```
extends layout

block main
    .container.backgroundimage
        h1 Hello world
```

I tried doing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29089925/pass-variables-to-base-layout-from-extending-jade-template) as suggested in the comments below and set my `body_class = index` in index.jade. And tried to style `.index` in css but this is not working also.

So is there a way I can accomplish this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29089925/pass-variables-to-base-layout-from-extending-jade-template has your answer.

Comment: basically, you need to modify your layout to apply a class the the body tag if that variable is set, and then set it from within your page.

Comment: @WoodrowBarlow I tried doing this, and made `body_class = 'index'` in index.jade, and tried to style `.index` in css, but does not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either you need to add the index class to your document body, using something like this (or an equivalent after the page is loaded).

```
extends layout

block main
    - document.getElementByTagName("body").classList.add("index")
    .container.backgroundimage
        h1 Hello world
```

Or you could simply apply the `.index` class to the container element on your `index` page, and make sure that container spans the entire page background. (This may or may not make sense depending on the contents of your layout).

Answer (score 1):

I have accepted the above answer but I ended up just creating a separate style sheet that customized the page. Seems to be a much more simple solution.